# Laravel total products count from childs in parent category

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, parent-child, categories

I have eloquent relationships with category child

**In category Model**

```
public function products()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Products::class, 'category', 'id');
    }

   public function sub() {
          return $this->hasMany(SELF::class, 'parent_id')->withCount(['products'])->with('sub');
   }
```

I would like to get in each category and child category has products count

Example
Category A is the parent
Category B and C are child of A category
Category B has 3 products and category C 2 products

How to get product_count 5 (total of B and C category product count) in the A parent category when I call withCount()?

At the moment there is 0 count but child categories have product count.

Thank you so much for any idea!

Comment: Which is max nesting? I mean, if category B and C can have childrens

Comment: Basically I would get unlimited quantity of childs for every single category.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the count of all products for a category including products under it's sub categories can be via two separate queries.

Assume:

- Category A has id of 5
- Category B and Category C are sub categories of A

```php
//Get the Category record with sub categories
//Select only id column from category
//Select id & parent_id (required as it links the relation) from sub (categories)
$category = Category::with('sub:id,parent_id')
    ->select('id')
    ->findOrFail(5);

//Prepare a collection of just the id's 
$categoryIds = $category->sub->pluck('id')->push($category->id);

//Get the product count
$count = Products::whereIn('category', $categoryIds)->count();
```

> I appreciate that! It's only got products count from 2 next child, not whole nested categories.

Define a method to get all ids from the subcategories

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function getSubcategoryIds()
    {
        $ids = $this->sub->pluck('id');
        
        $this->sub->each(function($sub) use(&$ids){            
            if($sub->sub->count()) {            
                $ids->push($sub->getSubcategoryIds());
            }
        });      

        return $ids->flatten();
    }

    //... rest of the class code
}
```

Then

```php
$category = Category::findOrFail(5);

//Get the subcategory ids deeply nested and add category id to it
$categoryIds = $category->getSubcategoryIds()->push($category->id);


//Get the product count
$count = Products::whereIn('category', $categoryIds)->count();
```

Comment: I appreciate that! It's only got products count from 2 next child, not whole nested categories.

Comment: So how many levels deep is the nesting. For eg: Category B has a subcategory D and D has a subcategory X and so on - how many such levels deep?

Comment: In every parent category, I have a different amount of nesting. Is there any chance to check how many parent category has nested.

Comment: Different amount of nesting is okay - but how many maximum levels of nesting can be there?

Comment: At the moment it should be not exceeding  more than 6 child categories

Comment: Have updated the answer to account for deep nesting of subcategories - check it out

Comment: Thank you! I have now all nested ids for each child category which it owns and including a parent category. Problem SOLVED :)

Comment: Glad that solution work for you. Pls remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors